# Facebook Invite with parameter

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm building a Facebook application that sends a request to a user using *fb-request-form* and *fb-multi-friend-selector*. I would like to know how I can add a parameter so that when the user clicks on the invite I can know who invited the user to my application.
I've tried both *fb-req-choice* and a *fb-protected* hidden input field but I didn't manage to achieve this with either of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently track the inviting user by adding a querystring parameter (such as from=[userid]) to the fb:req-choice url.

Comment: Can you little more specific??

Comment: When I use req-choice and add a parameter to the querystring I don't get the parameter from facebook when the invite is accepted.  This doesn't seem to work.